# Transform a CompletableFuture of a list of objects to another CompletableFuture of a list of objects

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a method (`getIds`) that returns a `CompletableFuture<List<String>>`. For each of the IDs in the list it returns, I need to call a method that fetches the corresponding username for that ID. That fetching takes some time, so it returns a `CompletableFuture` of `String`. Ultimately the method should return a `CompletableFuture` of the usernames `List<String>`:

```
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getUsernames() {
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> future = getIds();
    return future.thenCompose(ids -> {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(ids.stream()
                .map(this::getUsername)
                ...);
    });

private CompletableFuture<String> getUsername(String id) {
    ...
}
```

Can anyone advise how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The [`BetterFuture`](https://github.com/mduerig/better-future) library I wrote some time ago makes this quite easy:

```
public BetterFuture<List<String>> getUsernames() {
    BetterFuture<List<String>> future = getIds();

    return future.andThen(ids ->
        BetterFuture.reduce(ids.stream().map(this::getUsername))
        .map(Stream::toList));
}
```

`BetterFuture.reduce` reduces a `Stream<BetterFuture<T>>` to a `BetterFuture<Stream<T>>` and acts in parallel on the stream of futures it receives as an argument.

Since `BetterFuture` is just thin wrapper around `CompletableFuture`, it shouldn't be too hard to peel the the relevant implementation out and make above snippet work directly on `CompletableFuture`.